# How to assign a job name from Classic designer in Azure Pipelines?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm using Classic pipeline in the Azure Pipelines. I have a multi-job pipeline. I'd like to get multi-job output variables from the first job and use as a condition on my second job. No matter how I setup, I just can't get the output variable from the first job.

[image]

I always get `Null` for my output variables.

[image]

I'm sure I have been set the output variable:

[image]

I doubted that maybe the job name is unset. It because on the Web UI, I can only set `displayName` for a job. I can't really set a job name for a job.

I'd like to know that, is it possible to set job name on it when using classic design for a pipeline. Or how can I get the output variables from my second job and set as a condition?

See also: [Use the output variable from a job in a condition in a subsequent job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-4015686&tabs=classic%2Cstages#use-the-output-variable-from-a-job-in-a-condition-in-a-subsequent-job)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: echo "Sauce is $(sauce)"]

docs [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic%2Cbatch#use-outputs-in-a-different-job-1). It's better to use yaml.